# Какой частью речи является слово "необходимых" в данном предложении? Нужна ли запятая перед этим словом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастия, причастный-оборот

> Общество оказало Репину большую помощь по разысканию материалов,
> необходимых для выполнения заказа.

"Необходимых" — это причастие или нет? Является ли часть "необходимых для выполнения заказа" причастным оборотом?

Comment: Зря правите цитату. Так не принято делать, да и сложнее, чем скопировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Некоторые дополнения** к предыдущему ответу (объяснение дается строго по тексту вопроса)

*Общество оказало Репину большую помощь по разысканию **материАлов, необходимых для выполнения закАза.***

1. ***Необходимый*** – это причастие? Нет, это прилагательное, хотя ИМ –  суффикс страдательного причастия настоящего времени (сравнить: видимый). *Необходимый* –  самостоятельное слово, только формально связанное с глаголом *обходить*. В словарной статье определяется как «такой, без которого трудно, невозможно обойтись; нужный».
2. **Запятая нужна**. Мы обособляем разные определительные обороты (на основе причастий или прилагательных) по одним и тем же правилам. В данном случае оборот обособляется, так как стоит **после определяемого слова**.  В этом случае мы делаем паузу, а  ударение падает  и на определяемое слово, и на оборот.
3. **Всегда ли обособляются обороты в такой позиции**? Нет, есть исключения. Вот пример из Розенталя: *Попытки писать просто приводили к результатам печАльным и смешнЫм* (М. Г.) Здесь нет паузы, а есть **тесная связь** с определяемым словом:  ударение падает на оборот, но не падает на определяемое существительное.

Можно привести свой пример: *Позолоченную бронзу нельзя чистить **материалами химически активными или абразивными**.*

Answer (score 2):

(Какой?) необходимый - прилагательное.

***Общество оказало Репину большую помощь по разысканию материалов, необходимых для выполнения заказа.*** Запятая поставлена при обособлении определения, выраженного прилагательным с зависимыми словами, которое стоит после определяемого слова.

Обосабливается не только причастный оборот, но и прилагательное с зависимыми словами, и одиночные прилагательные, если они стоят после определяемого слова, или относятся к личному местоимению, или имеют добавочное обстоятельственное значение, или далеко отстоят от определяемого слова.